# Passing multiple objects to an event in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a method and in it i have some user tracking code

```
public function settings(Request $request)
    {
      $id = Auth::id();
      $now = new DateTime();
      $page = 'Settings Page';
      $monitor = new Monitoring;
      $users_full_names = Auth::user()->users_full_names;
      $country = 'unseen';
      $device = $agent->device();
      $platform = $agent->platform();
      $browser = $agent->browser();
      $date = $now->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
      $time = time();
      $ip = $request->ip();

      $data = compact('users_full_names','page','country','time','date','monitor','id', 'device', 'platform', 'browser', 'ip');

      Event::fire('simpleEvent', $data, $monitor);

      $uid = Auth::id();
      $settings = Settings::where('user_id','=',Auth::id())->first();
      return view('text.settings',compact('settings'));
    }
```

The method has this line that passes the data to the event

`Event::fire('simpleEvent', $data, $monitor);`

that i have defined. This is the event code that i have in `web.php`

```
  Event::listen('simpleEvent', function($data,$monitor){
  $monitor->monitoring_user_id = Auth::id();
  $monitor->monitoring_user_names = $data->users_full_names;
  $monitor->monitoring_page_visited = $data->page;
  $monitor->monitoring_ip = $data->ip;
  $monitor->monitoring_date_of_visit = $data->date;
  $monitor->monitoring_time_of_visit = $data->time;
  $monitor->monitoring_country = $data->country;
  $monitor->monitoring_date = $data->date;
  $monitor->monitoring_device = $data->platform;
  $monitor->save();
  });
```

When i run the code i get this error

> at HandleExceptions->handleError(2, 'Attempt to assign property of
>   non-object', '/var/www/html/letextify/routes/web.php', 14,
>   array('data' => 'Radagast', 'monitor' => 'Successfully Logged In')) in
>   web.php line 14

this is line `14`

`$monitor->monitoring_user_id = Auth::id();`

This is the `dd($data)` output

```
array:10 [▼
  "users_full_names" => "Radagast"
  "page" => "Successfully Logged In"
  "country" => "unseen"
  "time" => 1495705235
  "date" => "2017-05-25 09:40:35"
  "monitor" => Monitoring {#331 ▼
    #table: "monitoring"
    #connection: null
    #primaryKey: "id"
    #keyType: "int"
    +incrementing: true
    #with: []
    #withCount: []
    #perPage: 15
    +exists: false
    +wasRecentlyCreated: false
    #attributes: []
    #original: []
    #casts: []
    #dates: []
    #dateFormat: null
    #appends: []
    #events: []
    #observables: []
    #relations: []
    #touches: []
    +timestamps: true
    #hidden: []
    #visible: []
    #fillable: []
    #guarded: array:1 [▶]
  }
  "device" => false
  "platform" => "Ubuntu"
  "browser" => "Firefox"
  "ip" => "100.208.40.100"
]
```

How can correct the error?.

Comment: what is the output of `dd(Auth::id())`?

Comment: That ouputs 11 which is current logged in user user id.

Answer (score 0):

**Add id to $data Array**

Add 'id' in your compact array. so that it will be available in $data->id

```
$data = compact('id', 'users_full_names','page','country','time','date','monitor','id', 'device', 'platform', 'browser', 'ip');
```

$monitor is already available in $data. So you can change you code as below:

**Change Fire Code**

```
Event::fire('simpleEvent', $data);
```

**Change Listen Code**

**Also no need to call Auth::id() again as it is available in $data->id, check the code below:**

```
Event::listen('simpleEvent', function($data){

  $monitor = $data->monitor;                            //check this line

  $monitor->monitoring_user_id = $data->id;             //check this line

  $monitor->monitoring_user_names = $data->users_full_names;
  $monitor->monitoring_page_visited = $data->page;
  $monitor->monitoring_ip = $data->ip;
  $monitor->monitoring_date_of_visit = $data->date;
  $monitor->monitoring_time_of_visit = $data->time;
  $monitor->monitoring_country = $data->country;
  $monitor->monitoring_date = $data->date;
  $monitor->monitoring_device = $data->platform;
  $monitor->save();
  });
```

Comment: @WolfEyes , I edited my answer, I forgot that 'id' was not available in $data. Please see the first heading 'Add id to $data Array'

Answer (score 0):

I solved it this way

```
Event::listen('simpleEvent', function($data){
  $monitor = $data['monitor'];
  $monitor->monitoring_user_id = $data['id'];
  $monitor->monitoring_user_names = $data['users_full_names'];
  $monitor->monitoring_page_visited = $data['page'];
  $monitor->monitoring_ip = $data['ip'];
  $monitor->monitoring_date_of_visit = $data['date'];
  $monitor->monitoring_time_of_visit = $data['time'];
  $monitor->monitoring_country = $data['country'];
  $monitor->monitoring_date = $data['date'];
  $monitor->monitoring_device = $data['platform'];
  $monitor->save();
  });
```